# How to draw line/multiline, polygon/multipolygon with SharpMap from Coordinate Source

Tags: c#, vb.net, json, polygon-creation, sharpmap

I have a list of n points, exactly x objects in GeoJSON from a CouchDB. I want to generate lines/multilines and polygons/mutipolygons with
[SharpMap](https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and add this to a Layer in VB.NET. For points its easy, but for the rest: I don't get it. Must I use ICoordinateSequence?

So, can anybody post here some example to generate such geometries **dynamically** from coord-list-like text- or GeoJSON/JSON-Sources (maybe here its another workaround than for plain text?), much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at:

    `var jsonSerializer = new NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJsonSerializer();
    jsonSerializer.Deserialize(...)`

Comment: how i get this into a featurelayer? Do you have an example? (c# is ok, too)